# How to add multiple classes to an img element

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I am tring to add a class sprite to all the images. Moreover if eachName[1] is bulbasaur, I want to add a class found to it, and otherwise I want to add a class unfound to them. This code could catch a class sprite correctly, but could not catch found/unfound. Is there something wrong in this code? Thanks.

```
            var picArr = this.responseText.split("\n");
            for(var i=0; i < picArr.length; i++){
                var eachName = picArr[i].split(":")
                var spriteurl = "/Pokedex/sprites/" + eachName[1];
                var imgClass = 'sprite';
                if(eachName[1]==='bulbasaur.png'){
                    imgClass += ' found';
                } else {
                    imgClass += ' unfound';
                }
                document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML += "<img src=" + spriteurl + " class=" + imgClass + ">";
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing escaped quotes in your `innerHTML` output.

```
document.getElementById("pokedex-view").innerHTML += "<img src=\"" + spriteurl + "\" class=\"" + imgClass + "\">";
```

Also, if you want to **add** the class `found` and `unfound` it should be :

```
            if(eachName[1]==='bulbasaur.png'){
                imgClass += ' found';
            } else {
                imgClass += ' unfound';
            }
```

Otherwise you're losing the `sprite` class by re-assigning the `imgClass` variable instead of appending to it.

Comment: I tried the code you suggested. In the code, that could catch the class found/unfound. But instead, that could not catch the class "sprite"...

Comment: instead of `imgClass = ' found'` and `imgClass = ' unfound'` it should be `imgClass += ' found'` and `imgClass += ' unfound'`, I've updated my response to reflect that.